Replace LegacyCamera with Camera2
In this device with AOSP 10, I have currently the LegacyCamera API for the camera but I want to replace it with Camera2.
What should I change to have it build and install Camera2 by default instead of LegacyCamera?
Thanks

(I'm assuming you mean the LegacyCamera and Camera2 applications, not APIs)
Somewhere in your device's .mk files, there's a line that adds the LegacyCamera package, probably something like
  PRODUCT_PACKAGES += LegacyCamera

Replace LegacyCamera with Camera2 in that line.

Hi, I did mean the application, not the API. I have added the PRODUCT_PACKAGES += Camera2 line in the .mk file but it is not building it. It installs the app when I build it manually, but it doesn't build it automatically. If I do a make clean, it the app won't be there after I install. Do you know what else I might need to add?

My only thought is that you're not changing it in the right .mk file.  Do other changes to the .mk file get reflected in the built product?

In one of the .mk files I modified, if I include LegacyCamera, it gets installed. However, if I replace LegacyCamera with Camera2, LegacyCamera disappears and Camera2 is not installed.
I'll try with other .mk files anyway,

That's very odd. Unfortunately I don't know why it's behaving like that.
